# Table layout "cutting off" checkBox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have problem with check boxes. Looks like my TableLayout is "cutting off" tops and bottoms. Maybe it's simple question, but i don't know how to prevent it. I want to make padding between columns too, but it shouldn't be a problem i think.

[image]

And this is my xml code:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#0099cc"
        tools:context="com.example.skypedogg.srvapp.PinPadActivity">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">
        </View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
                style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/black_overlay"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                    style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
                    android:text="OK" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="50dp">

            <TableRow>
                <net.igenius.customcheckbox.CustomCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check1"
                    app:color_checked="@color/usafaBlue"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <net.igenius.customcheckbox.CustomCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check2"
                    app:color_checked="@color/usafaBlue"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <net.igenius.customcheckbox.CustomCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check3"
                    app:color_checked="@color/usafaBlue"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <net.igenius.customcheckbox.CustomCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check4"
                    app:color_checked="@color/usafaBlue"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What if u give some margin to net.igenius.customcheckbox.CustomCheckBox? or decrease the padding of TableLayout and try?

Comment: Remove `android:padding="50dp"` from `TableLayout`

Comment: Remove `padding ="50dp" ` from TableLayout

Comment: Thanks Raghavendra, I knew it would be something simple, and i tried with padding Ali, and this doesn't work, and anyway i need paddings there Ali.

Comment: @SkypeDogg why you need padding there ???

Comment: to keep some space from top, left, right, and bottom (because it's not the end of layout)

Comment: Then you use `margin_top`, `margin_left`, and `margin_right`.  but remove `padding` @SkypeDogg

Comment: So that's why i made it @Raghavendra way, and with padding + margin CheckBoxes are in lower position and smaller, and look just as I want. And for bottom I want to have padding, so for me it's better to use just padding, instead of 3 different margins (code is bit cleaner).

Comment: okay as you wish but may be the problem is `padding` @SkypeDogg